# CakePHP - remove or turn off behaviour dynamically

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP, I am using the below behaviour in my model (in Table in initialize function):

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
         'b10' => [
            'fields' => [
                'dir' => 'logo',
            ],                     
        ]
    ]);
```

Is it possible to dynamically remove the above bahaviour on demand from the controller?
My problem is related to the fact that the above plugin allows me to save the file to my server and to set this information to my database, but I have troubles with removing the file on demand. With the addbehaviuor function, removing the information from the database is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$this->SomeModel->removeBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload');`

Comment: What is in this link? I cannot access it.